# Set date in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm experienced with Google Sheets, pretty inexperienced (but not completely noob) with Apps Script.

I have a Google Form at work. It's a leave request form. It has two fields:

- "First day of leave"
- "Last day of leave"

I would like that the "last day of leave" automatically equals "first day of leave" + 1 (bonus points for next working day!) as the user is filling the form out. This is so that people who are completing the form don't have to scroll through all the months on two occasions to apply for leave (which they keep stuffing up).

I've read about the DateItem class, but there isn't a method to set (pre-set) the value.

Is there a way to do what I'm looking to do?

Comment: if you know the last day of leave will allways equal firstday+1 and are willing to hardcode it- Perhaps it would be best to omit it from the user side and add the formula on the spreadsheet where the data is being collected?

Comment: I see what you're saying, but what I'm trying to do is link the two date questions so that people don't accidentally put a date in the past in the second field (a bit like when you book a flight on an airline webpage) ... hopefully that explains a little bit better what I'm looking for!

Comment: You could have a "number of work days" field. The user would select a number such as "3" then script some math and add 3 to the date?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No (not via Google Forms); Yes (via HTML-based simple web-app).

Unfortunately, you cannot change/edit/update Google Form items programatically as there are no [available triggers types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers) that would allow for such an action.

Hope this helps.